# Mitmproxy upstream server

Tags: python, proxy, mitmproxy

Trying to set upstream server in mitmproxy.

The scheme is very simple: Browser -> Mitmproxy -> Proxy -> AnyServer

Here is the code:
    import mitmproxy
    from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
    from netlib.http import Headers
    from mitmproxy import ctx

```
def request (flow):
    if flow.request.method == "CONNECT":
        return
    if flow.live:
        print (flow.request.host)
        address = ("92.247.125.246", 3128)
        flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(address)
```

After this a had the SetServerNotAllowedException:

[image]

I disabled HTTP/2 in my browser and now there is no errors, but on myip sites I see the IP of my  MITM proxy server! So it is not using the last proxy, why? Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

change_upstream_proxy_server is the function that can only CHANGE the upstream server. It can't enable it if the upstream server was not enabled earlier.

This mean that if you want to change upstream server you need to start mitmproxy with -U parameter, for example: mitmdump -U http://127.0.0.1:9999 -s server.py

After this you the change_upstream_proxy_server will work.

Comment: With current (4.x) versions, the syntax for upstream proxy is different. Instead of `-U http://....`, use `--mode upstream:http://foo.bar:9999`.

Comment: Does this also work for socks5 proxies? I have a VPN that offers a socks5 proxy behind the VPN (that works great in Firefox) but I can't get mitmproxy to upsteams to it.